# How to embedd a Qt widget in QML?

Tags: qt, qml

Suppose I write the code for a pushbutton widget in Qt (C++).
Is it possible to **display** that pushbutton in QML window with Qt 4.8?

What do I need to read for that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qgraphicsproxywidget.html

http://qt-project.org/wiki/QtDesktopComponents

But the whole idea of QML is to create your own custom buttons with it, a whole custom QML GUI.

Comment: Agreed. It is completely feasible, but I cannot see any good reason for doing so.
Maybe the OP should look for the DesktopComponents :)